# Semantics: Empty div for background image

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I know that an empty div is not *hmmm* entirely semantical. But I was wondering if it's okay to use it with a background image to create a nicely styled dropshadow or other effects to decorate a 'parent' div.

(Also I know how I can do this with CSS3 but for obvious reasons this won't always do the trick)

Comment: If you just want a dropshadow you can use css3's `box-shadow`. I hope you know of this site: http://css3please.com/

Comment: Thanks mate, this is a bit of a late reply but I haven't noticed your response before. I do know how to use box-shadow, but it doesn't always quite nicely do what I had in mind so in some cases I prefer doing my dropshadows and/or other effects beforehand in photoshop.

Comment: Semantically, there is nothing wrong in using an empty `div`(or `span`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave the html as clean as possible the very best thing to do would be to, well... to leave it alone and use CSS. How? CSS gives you a way to add [pseudo]elements into the html with two special selectors: :after and :before. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/ubG5t/

The css, if you can't see it in the fiddle, looks like the following:

```
body:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  /* your styles */
}
```

There's not much to it. What it does is insert at the very end of the body element (still inside of it), a [pseudo]element with a display of block - just like a div. You can give it it whichever styles you like - again, it's just like having a regular div [1*]

The content thing is there to make it work. You can put some text inside of it, which will appear in the box, or you can just leave it empty like I did - but it needs to be there, otherwise, no div for you.

**1 - well, transitions don't really work with it, but apart from that...*

Comment: If you for some reason can't use "pseudo elements", then just put an empty div in the html - I wouldn't worry a bit about it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! This thing's been bugging me ever since I started developing websites. My world has become a whole lot brighter now ;)

Answer (score 4):

It may not be good style, but technically it is valid to add an empty `div` element.

Because `div` doesn't add or change any meaning, the use of an empty `div` doesn't interfere with the semantics of your document.

Of course you should provide the background image with CSS and not with the `img` element.

However, maybe you could achieve your desired deocation with CSS pseudo-elements `after` and `before` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.element div:empty{
    background: #red;
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
} 
</style>


<div class="element">
<div>not empty</div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.